# The Wrapper Constructors get NumberFormatException:

Tags: java, wrapper, numberformatexception

```
Float f1 = new Float("12.6f");
```

In this above code I didn't get any exception. But the below code I got 
`NumberFormatException`:

```
Long l1= new Long("200L");
```

I know all of the wrapper classes except Character provide two constructors

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(42); //Primitive
Integer i2 = new Integer("42"); // String
Float f1 = new Float(3.14f); //Primitive
Float f2 = new Float("3.14f"); // String
```

So why I get exception for this

```
Long l1= new Long("200L");
```

why this didn't

```
Float f2 = new Float("3.14f");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation on the constructors

For `Long`, it defers to `Long.parseLong`, which does not accept strings ending in `L`. However `Float` has different parsing behavior depending on whether it is provided with `3.14d` or `3.14f`, so these are both valid inputs for that specific constructor.